# Get current country pathPrefix

Tags: 8, path-aliases

How can I get current country pathPrefix in D8 ?

I know `drupalSettings.path.pathPrefix` gives that in JS, but how can I get it in preprocess hook ?

Following gives only the path alias, but without pathPrefix.

```
\Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/'.$nid[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [PathProcessorManager::processOutbound()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21PathProcessor%21PathProcessorManager.php/function/PathProcessorManager%3A%3AprocessOutbound/8.5.x) for the internal path and you get the path alias and the prefix at the same time:

```
$options = ['prefix' => ''];
$path = \Drupal::service('path_processor_manager')->processOutbound('/node/1', $options);
$prefix = $options['prefix'];
```